# Css computed color different from specified color

Tags: html, css

I have used the following color for css.

```
a:link,
a:active {
   color: #e67e22;
   text-decoration: none;
   padding-bottom: 1px; 
   border-bottom: 1px solid #e67e22;
}

a:active,
a:hover {
  color: #555;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding-bottom: 1px; 
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e67e22;
}
```

This is the corresponding html

```
<a href="#">@omnifood_berlin</a>
```

But the color being displayed or computed is different as shown below.

[image]

What can be a reason for this? How can I make it the color I specified?

Comment: Have you tried `a { color: #e67e22; }`

Comment: `#e67e22` is `rgb(230,126,34)`,,,,so what is your question

Comment: ...also clear that cache.

Comment: @Paulie_D  No, rgb(85,26,139) is being applied.

Comment: @KayakinKoder That worked. But I have given all the four states. Modified the question accordingly. WHy does it come as blue?

Comment: Apparently you forgot to style the default state and styled the `:active` state twice. `#551a8b` or `rgb(85, 26, 139)` is the default color for a visited link in most browsers. Perhaps you meant to also set a rule for `:visited`?

Comment: Sorry.My bad. Modified active to visited. I was constantly overlooking it. It worked all fine. Should I delete the question as its a silly mistake?

Comment: If my solution worked, selecting my answer would be better than deleting :) thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, add this as mentioned in my comment:

`a { color: #e67e22; }`

Also note that you have `active` twice, as mentioned in a comment. Next, read through the official docs https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_link.asp particularly this bit

> When setting the style for several link states, there are some order
>   rules:
>
> a:hover MUST come after a:link and a:visited a:active MUST come after
>   a:hover

Follow those rules and I think your problem will be resolved.